# Finding the Fourier Integral Transformation of a function

Tags: integration, transformation, fourier-transform

How can I find the Fourier Integral representation of;

$$f(x) = xe^{-|x|}$$

Without looking it up or using transform tables.

Comment: Try computing the Fourier transform directly.

Comment: can you please show me how to do that?

Comment: Look up the definition.

Comment: try integrating by parts $\int_0^\infty f(x) e^{-2i \pi \xi x} dx = \int_0^\infty x e^{-(1+2i \pi \xi) x} dx$

Comment: By Fourier integral representation, you mean, I think, the Fourier Transform ?

Comment: @user1952009, can you please show me how to implement this?

Comment: do you know any function whose derivative is $g'(x) = e^{-(1+2i\pi \xi)x}$ ?

Comment: @user1952009 no I do not.